# How do I call the returned inner function of another function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to solve a problem from an online tutorial. Consider the following function:

```
var badFunction = function() {
  return function() {
    return "veryBad"
  }
}
```

Here, `badFunction` returns a function that returns `"veryBad"`. I want to store `"veryBad"` inside `theBad`. How can I call the returned inner function? This answer isn't acceptable:

```
var theBad = "veryBad!";
```

Neither is this:

```
var theBad = badFunction(); 
theBad();
```

Although both of those work. So how do I call the inner function?

Comment: The second one *does* call your inner function. You just don't do anything with the return value?! Try to `console.log(theBad())` it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just call the return value:

```
var theBad = badFunction()();
```

This will first call the function `badFunction`, then after the function finishes, it will then call the *returned function*. The evaluation looks something like this:

```
badFunction()();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Step 1, calls badFunction
```

Then, once `badFunction` is called, it returns an anonymous function expression:

```
(function() { // <-- This is the return value of badFunction
  return "veryBad"
})();
  ^^
  Step 2, call the returned function expression for "veryBad"
```

Of course, you could store the returned function in an intermediate variable, then call that:

```
var veryBadFunc = badFunction();
var theBad = veryBadFunc();
```

This would store the returned function in `veryBadFunc` which you could call later and store in `theBad`. This is exactly what you've done in your last try. The catch is that you have to *do something with the return value*, such as store it in a variable for later use.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the clear explanation.  I knew I was missing something, i.e., storing the return value.  I accepted your answer.